# :hover states "stick" when using React Router

Tags: css, reactjs, hover

LINK TO CODESANDBOX LINK: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-paper-qucsp

I'm happy to post more code if needed.

I'm learning React and I have a simple page setup with routes set to other components. The  tags have a className set and have hover/focus states. When I click on one of the  tags to load another component (page refreshes), the hover/focus state of those  tags remains until I 'click' somewhere else. I can even activate hover states on the other  tags while the original one in question still acts as if it's being hovered over. Can someone tell me why this happens/how to fix it/link me documentation that explains it?

Again, I'm happy to provide any other code if it's relevant. Thanks all.

A simple Nav.js and App.js are below to show what I'm working with. The Nav has  tags as well as  tags (for external sites), and the hover state 'sticks' on both tags.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="main-container">
        <Nav />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/About" component={About} />
          <Route path="/Projects" component={Projects} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

```
function Nav() {
    return (
          <nav>
            <Link to="/About" className="nav-link"><li>About</li></Link>
            <a href="randomlink.com" className="nav-link"target="_blank">link1</a>
            <Link to="/" className="homeLink"><li>Home</li></Link>
            <a href="randomlink.com" className="nav-link" target="_blank">link3</a>
            <Link to="/Projects" className="nav-link"><li>Projects</li></Link>
          </nav>
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you also include the CSS that is being applied to these "links"? And are you rendering `Link` components from react-router-dom, or `NavLink` components that you've renamed? Could you try creating a *running* codesandbox that recreates this issue that we may live debug in?

Comment: @DrewReese I added a CodeSandbox link to the post for reference. https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-paper-qucsp

Comment: Well, I answered below and then rechecked your codesandbox and TBH it didn't seem like I could reproduce actually the issue you describe, which leads me to believe I've misunderstood what you say the issue is (considering I feel also my answer is insufficient). Closest I could think is this scenario: A user tabs to a link and it has focus and is styled, and then the user hovers over another link, and it also styled. The link with focus will keep it until focus is moved elsewhere. Can you explain in clearer terms what the issue is? Provide a set of steps to reproduce it in your sandbox?

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for looking into it Reese. The second underline on the homeLink was intentional. I noticed Samrat responded below and advised me I was using a Focus state that was the cause of the issue. I suppose I can't remember the last time I matched focus state to hover state, so I forgot about the Focus state quirks. :P But I'll be looking into NavLink components at your request. Thanks!

Comment: So was it the scenario I described, with some element maintaining focus while you hover over others? If so then this is what I would expect with the sandbox code. I just tried Samrat's suggestion and decoupling hover and focus style appears to be what you want. Generally speaking you usually will want to leave the focus styles alone (for accessibility) unless you've a fairly custom component and it has suboptimal visual accessibility. Browsers generally already do a good job of indicating focus on items that are interacted with.

Answer (score 0):

> It is because you are applying scaleX(1) when the link is in focus. This is causing the underline to stick.

Change your css from:

```
.homeLink:hover::before,
.homeLink:focus::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
.nav-link:hover::after,
.nav-link:focus::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

To:

```
.homeLink:hover::before{
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
.nav-link:hover::after{
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Samrat. Thanks for letting me know about the Focus state causing the style to stick. I hadn't considered the element being in focus after a click. Do you know what a solution could be for a focus state (for accessibility reasons)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the extra underline is being caused by your `.homeLink::after` selector and CSS. When you hover over the home link you see this and the hover/focus underline get animated in.

```
.homeLink::after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

When I remove this selector the extra underline is removed and the hover/focus behavior appears to be as you intended.

[image: Edit hover-states-stick-when-using-react-router]

I think some of your CSS could be simplified if you switched to using [Navlink](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink) link components where you can specify style to apply against the link when it is active.